# Is there default properties file to put configurations into?

Tags: java

Any default properties file which java can automatcially load?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use your own default [properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) file. You can do it with just few lines.

There is also built in properties, however, these are no simpler, but they are standard.

IMHO Most of the time a plain Proeprties file is used.

This example from the tutorial. This is a more complex example, you can have just one properties file.

```
// create and load default properties
Properties defaultProps = new Properties();
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("defaultProperties");
defaultProps.load(in);
in.close();

// create application properties with default
Properties applicationProps = new Properties(defaultProps);

// now load properties from last invocation
in = new FileInputStream("appProperties");
applicationProps.load(in);
in.close();
```

Comment: where is defaultProperties located? Also, where is appProperties?

Comment: The strings `"defaultProperties"` and `"appProperties"` are file names.  They are wherever you put them.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is no.

The somewhat longer answer starts with a question itself: What should be configured by this file?

For the logging-API of java ([java.util.logging](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html)) exists a standard-properties-file to configure it. Other frameworks may as well use standard-configuration files. But that always configure only stuff specific for this framework.

If you want to have persistent configuration, you probably want to use the [Preference-API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/package-summary.html). That allows you to save configuration-data, that stays with the user or the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load your properties file yourself or pass arguments at command line.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small library that you can use which will load properties automatically for you: [Confucius](http://github.com/ivanTrendafilov/Confucius).